# Testes do jest retornando erro em coisas simples

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-automatizados, jest

Estou iniciando os estudos nos testes e criei dois dos mais simples possíveis, soma e multiplicação, com o seguinte trecho no arquivo `index.js`:

```py
const sum = (a, b) => a + b 
const multiply = (c, d) => c * d
module.exports = sum, multiply
```

Após isso, em outro arquivo, o `index.test.js`, executei o seguinte trecho:

```py
const sum = require("./index.js");
const multiply = require("./index.js");

    test("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
      expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
    });
    
    test("adds 7 + 2 to equal 9", () => {
      expect(sum(7, 2)).toBe(9);
    });
    
    test("should 9 multiplying 3 return 27", () => {
      expect(multiply(9, 3)).toBe(27);
    });
```

Os dois primeiros testes de soma funcionam corretamente, porém no último, ele retorna o seguinte erro, após executar o comando de `yarn test`.

```
Expected: 27
    Received: 12

      11 |
      12 | test("should 9 multiplying 3 return 27", () => {
    > 13 |   expect(multiply(9, 3)).toBe(27);
```

Ou seja, a função de `multiply` está somando, e não multiplicando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fez a exportação apenas da primeira função, no caso `sum`.

Para exportar múltiplas funções, você pode exportar como Objeto usando uma das seguintes abordagens:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b 
const multiply = (c, d) => c * d
module.exports = { sum, multiply } // Multiplas funções em um objeto
```

Ou:

```
exports.sum = (a, b) => a + b 
exports.multiply = (c, d) => c * d
```

Então, no arquivo de testes, você importa usando a [desestruturação de objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#desestrutura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objeto), da seguinte forma:

```
const {sum, multiply} = require("./index.js");
```

E todos os testes funcionam adequadamente:

```
PASS  index.test.js
  ✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (2 ms)
  ✓ adds 7 + 2 to equal 9 (1 ms)
  ✓ should 9 multiplying 3 return 27

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.229 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /index.test.js/i.
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado. Perdão pelo erro "Noob" rsrs. Me ajudou muito. =)

Comment: Se foi útil, não esqueça de avaliar minha resposta como +1 e marcar a mesma como escolhida.